# AngularJS $routeProvider resolve not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) tutorial for routing in Angular.  Here is the example it gives for using resolve:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
})
```

Here is my route provider:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/agency/add',
    {
        controller: 'agencyController',
        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Content/templates/agencyUpsert.html',
        resolve: {
            lookup: ['lookupService', function (lookupService) {
                //lookupService.getLookups().then(function (response) {
                //    return response.data;
                //});
                return lookupService.getLookups();
            }]
        }
    })
```

Here is my lookup service:

```
angular.module('app').factory('lookupService', ['$http', 'baseApiUrl', function ($http, baseApiUrl) {
    var getLookups = function () {
        $http.get(baseApiUrl + 'api/lookups/').then(function (data) {
            return data.data;
        });
    };
    return {
        getLookups: getLookups
    };
}]);
```

And lastly, my controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('agencyController', ['$scope', 'lookup',
    function ($scope, lookup) {
        $scope.states = lookup.states;
    }
}]);
```

The lookupService (and server-side API) indeed get hit, but the error I'm getting is that lookup is undefined when I try to assign `$scope.states` in my controller.

Why is it not properly injecting the dependency into my controller via my route resolve?

Comment: Isn't your data just in lookup, so `$scope.states = lookup;` should fix it?

Comment: @ilmgb: `states` is a property on `lookup`.  It's just one of many potential lookup values.  `lookup` is undefined when that line is executed.

Comment: You probably need to put a return before the `$http.get` line. As is stands getLookups returns undefined.

Comment: @jsonmurphy: Wow.  Thanks.  How dumb.  If you make your comment an answer, I'll make it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a missing `return` in your `getLookups` function in the `lookupService`:

```
angular.module('app').factory('lookupService', ['$http', 'baseApiUrl', function ($http, baseApiUrl) {
  var getLookups = function () {
    // changed here
    return $http.get(baseApiUrl + 'api/lookups/').then(function (data) {
      return data.data;
    });
  };
  return {
    getLookups: getLookups
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect is something to do with your service factory, since the request is hit on the API, i doubt the factory is returning data from there on.

Can you check with this.

```
angular.module('app').factory('lookupService', ['$http', 'baseApiUrl', function ($http, baseApiUrl) {

    var lookups = {};
    lookups.getLookups = function () {
        $http.get(baseApiUrl + 'api/lookups/').success(function (data) {
            return data;
        }).error(function(data,status){
          console.log('failed with ' + status); // you need to work on this
        });
    };

    return lookups;
}]);
```

Note i have changed data.data to data, if you really have it wrapped like that change it.